# How to resolve Actually there were zero interactions with this mock error in Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to run the test class but the error **actually there were zero interactions** is thrown.

```
 class Xtractor{
     void extractValues(request,Map m1, Map m2,Map m3){
         //doesSomething..
     }
 } 

 class Sample{
     public void extractMap(){
     x.extractValues(request,m1,m2,m3);
    }
 }

 class SampleTest{
     @Mock
     Xtractor xtractor;

     @Mock
     Sample sample;

     @Before
     public void setup(){
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
         xtractor=mock(Xtractor.class);
         ArgumentCaptor<Map> m1= ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Map.class);
         ArgumentCaptor<Map> m2= ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Map.class);
         ArgumentCaptor<Map> m3= ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Map.class);
         ArgumentCaptor<HttpServletRequest> request= 
               ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HttpServletRequest.class);
     }

     @Test
     public void  testmapExtractor(){
         Mockito.verify(xtractor).extractValues( request.capture(),m1.capture(),m2.capture(),m3.capture());
     }
}
```

I have looked into the sourcecode most of the time but not able to get what I am missing in the above test class

Answer (score 1):

In your test case you are attempting to verify that `xtractor.extractMap()` is invoked but you do not invoke that method anywhere in your test. (On a side note: there's some confusion between `extractMap` - which you reference in your test case - and `extractValues` which you show in your example code).

Assuming that `Sample` is provided with an instance of `Xtractor` and that `Sample` exposes a public method which uses that instance of `Xtractor` then you would test that public method on `Sample` as follows:

```
public class Sample {

    private Xtractor xtractor;

    public Sample(Xtractor xtractor) {
        this.extractor = extractor;
    }

    public void doIt(HttpServletRequest request, Map m1, Map m2, Map m3) {
        x.extractValues(request,m1,m2,m3);
    }      
}

@Test
public void testmapExtractor() {
    // create an instance of the class you want to test
    Sample sample = new Sample(xtractor);

    // invoke a public method on the class you want to test
    sample.doIt();

    // verify that a side effect of the mehod you want to test is invoked
    Mockito.verify(xtractor).extractMap(request.capture(), m1.capture(), m2.capture(), m3.capture());
}
```

This example will work though it looks a little bit odd (you have a method named `extractValues` which is typed `void` ... the `Sample` class provided in your question has no body etc) but the rudiments are in place in this example, namely;

- `Xtractor` is mocked
- The mocked instance of `Xtractor` is passed into `Sample`
- `Sample` is tested
- The secondary call from `Sample` to `Xtractor` is verified

**Edit 1**: based on these comments "Can I test xtractor.extractValues() even if this call is not in Sample class ... Ok, here I will remove the @Mock from Xtractor, how do I test xtractor.extractValues()" the desired answer might be:

```
@Test
public void testmapExtractor() {
    // create an instance of the class you want to test
    Xtractor xtractor = new Xtractor();

    // invoke a public method on the class you want to test
    xtractor.extractValues();

    // assert 
    // ...
    // without knowing exactly what extractValues does it's impossible to say what the assert block should look like
}
```

Comment: Here Sample, Xtractor and SampleTest are all three files. Can you please let me know where exactly the issue in  my code is.

Comment: The issue is that your test case **never** calls `xtractor.extractValues()` and hence your attempt to verify that call fails. So, I provided an example test case which does calls `xtractor.extractValues` and I provided a bullet point list describing the principles of test/mock/verify.

Comment: Can I test xtractor.extractValues() even if this call is not in Sample class?

Comment: Yes you can but if you want **test** `xtractor.extractValues()` then you will **not** want to mock `Xtractor`. There might be a misunderstanding of the role of mocks here. Mocks are used to facilitate tests but if you want to test Class A then you cannot mock ClassA otherwise your test is useless.

Comment: Ok, here I will remove the @Mock from Xtractor, how do I test xtractor.extractValues()

Comment: I've updated my answer but since the `extractValues()` method in your question is empty it is impossible to know what the assertions should be. However, since you are now talking about testing `xtractor.extractValues()` I cannot see how Mockito needs to be involved. This is a straightforward, no-mocks, JUnit test unless there is some other class in use inside `xtractor.extractValues()`.

Comment: One more addition to the code I forgot, there is other SampleImpl class, in which doIt() is called and x.extractValues(request,m1,m2,m3); is called but the  instance of Xtractor is provided only in the  Sample class. Now I am writing testcase for SampleImpl class and want to test  x.extractValues(request,m1,m2,m3);

Comment: I think this chat has gotten too long now :) Anyway, I think I covered the case where Sample calls Xtractor in my original answer.

Comment: It helped me a lot, but the problem is that the instance of Xtractor is in Sample class and xtractor.extractValues() is used in SampleImpl class. How do I verify it.